# MDADM remove drive during recovery

Tags: linux, raid, software-raid

I would like to know that can I remove a drive during a recovery process from a RAID1 array:

What happend is that SDD had bad sectors, I removed it with

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdd1
mdadm --manage /dev/md0 --remove /dev/sdd1
```

Which although succeeded it crippled the machine in speed so I decided to readd it, now it's rebuilding itself:

```
md0 : active raid1 sdd1[0] sde1[2]
      976760400 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [_U]
      [>....................]  recovery =  4.0% (39768768/976760400) finish=19856.6min speed=786K/sec
```

During this recovery process (since it's raid1), I would assume that all it's doing is copying the content of the good drive (sde1) over to sdd. Is it safe to remove SDD again during this recovery? That's all I want to know.

Thanks

Comment: I'm also wondering this.  Obviously you can shut the system down and pull the disk, and rebuild onto a new disk after boot.  Be nice to be able to find quickly if there is a way to do it without shutting the system down.

Answer (score 0):

If you removed the new disk, you will interrupt the raid rebuild process. Why would you do that?

If you want to lower the speed of raid rebuild, you can play with this variable:

```
/proc/sys/dev/raid/speed_limit_max
```

Comment: Hello, because I readded the old (badsector) disk to the array by mistake. Now what I'm curious about is that can I safely mark this disk as failed and remove it again or have to wait out this whole recovery process?